# Type inference inconsistency with Any-value Map

Tags: scala, type-inference, type-erasure

In fiddling with a snippet that involves using a Map of Any-typed values as shown below, I encountered some type-inference inconsistency problem:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

case class AnyValMap[K]( m: Map[(K, TypeTag[_]), Any] ) extends AnyVal {
  def add[V](k: K, v: V)(implicit tag: TypeTag[V]) = this.copy(
      m = this.m + ((k, tag) -> v)
    )
  def grab[V](k: K)(implicit tag: TypeTag[V]): V = m((k, tag)).asInstanceOf[V]
}

val avMap = AnyValMap[String](Map.empty).
  add("a", 100).
  add("b", "xyz").
  add("c", 5.0).
  add("d", List(1, 2, 3))
// avMap: AnyValMap[String] = AnyValMap( Map(
//   (a,TypeTag[Int]) -> 100, (b,TypeTag[String]) -> xyz, (c,TypeTag[Double]) -> 5.0,
//   (d,TypeTag[List[Int]]) -> List(1, 2, 3)
// ) )

avMap.grab[Int]("a")
// res1: Int = 100

avMap.grab[String]("b")
// java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: (b,TypeTag[String]) ...

avMap.grab[Double]("c")
// res3: Double = 5.0

avMap.grab[List[Int]]("d")
// java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: (d,TypeTag[scala.List[Int]]) ...
```

Now, had I assembled the Map with explicit type info in `add[V]`, things would work fine:

```
val avMap = AnyValMap[String](Map.empty).
  add[Int]("a", 100).
  add[String]("b", "xyz").
  add[Double]("c", 5.0).
  add[List[Int]]("d", List(1, 2, 3))

avMap.grab[Int]("a")
// res5: Int = 100

avMap.grab[String]("b")
// res6: String = xyz

avMap.grab[Double]("c")
// res7: Double = 5.0

avMap.grab[List[Int]]("d")
// res8: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Questions I have re: `avMap` assembled in the former way:

1. `avMap` appears to have captured all the inferred types in the corresponding type-tags.  Why do some of them fail in looking up?
2. Why is there inconsistency in looking up Map values of types between `Int/Double` versus `String/List[T]`?  Maybe, something to do with how TypeTag handles types under `AnyVal` versus `AnyRef`?

I'm using Scala 2.11.12 (and 2.12.x seems to show the same inconsistency).  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inferred type when you call `avMap.add(List(1, 2, 3))` is `scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]`. But when you call `avMap.grab[List[Int]]`, the type `scala.List[Int]` is used instead.  This `scala.List` is an alias defined in `package object scala`.

Scala understands that those types are equivalent:

```
scala> typeOf[scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]] =:= typeOf[scala.List[Int]]
res1: Boolean = true
```

But they are still different types from the point of view of `TypeTag` and their types and type tags have different hash codes, so they are different keys in a `Map`:

```
scala> typeTag[scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]].hashCode()
res2: Int = 629297926

scala> typeTag[scala.List[Int]].hashCode()
res3: Int = 1684352762
```

The same thing happens with `String` which is an alias for `java.lang.String` defined in `scala.Predef`. The type of a string constant is `java.lang.String`, but when you use `String` type as a type parameter, it means `scala.Predef.String`.

The approach of storing types as keys is very fragile anyway. You'll also have problems with subtypes. For example, `map.add(Some(10))` infers the type to be `Some[Int]` instead of the expected `Option[Int]`.

---

Unless you really want to store several values of different types under the same key, I'd suggest you store the type as part of the value, and on retrieval check that it fits the requested type:

```
case class AnyValMap[K]( m: Map[K, (Type, Any)] ) extends AnyVal {
  def add[V](k: K, v: V)(implicit tag: TypeTag[V]) = this.copy(
    m = this.m + (k -> (tag.tpe, v))
  )
  def grab[V](k: K)(implicit tag: TypeTag[V]): V = {
    val (tpe, value) = m(k)
    if (tpe <:< tag.tpe) value.asInstanceOf[V]
    else throw new NoSuchElementException(s"wrong type $tpe of value for key: $k")
  }
}
```

This works well, and also allows to grab the values by their supertype:

```
scala> val avMap = AnyValMap[String](Map.empty).add("f", Some("abc"))

scala> avMap.grab[AnyRef]("f")
res4: AnyRef = Some(abc)

scala> avMap.grab[Option[AnyRef]]("f")
res5: Option[AnyRef] = Some(abc)

scala> avMap.grab[Option[String]]("f")
res6: Option[String] = Some(abc)

scala> avMap.grab[Option[Int]]("f")
java.util.NoSuchElementException: wrong type scala.Some[java.lang.String] of value for key: f
  at AnyValMap$.grab$extension(<console>:28)
  ... 31 elided
```

---

If you *do* want to have several values of different types under the same key, probably the best you can do is a linear search through a sequence of all values for a key:

```
case class AnyValMap[K]( m: Map[K, Vector[(Type, Any)]] ) extends AnyVal {
  def add[V](k: K, v: V)(implicit tag: TypeTag[V]) = this.copy(
    m = this.m + (k -> (this.m.getOrElse(k, Vector.empty) :+ (tag.tpe, v)))
  )
  def grab[V](k: K)(implicit tag: TypeTag[V]): V = {
    m(k).collectFirst {
      case (tpe, value: V @unchecked) if tpe <:< tag.tpe => value
    }.getOrElse(throw new NoSuchElementException(s"no suitable value for key: $k"))
  }
}

scala> val avMap = AnyValMap[String](Map.empty).
         add("a", List(1, 2, 3)).
         add("a", Some("abc"))

scala> avMap.grab[Seq[Int]]("a")
res20: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> avMap.grab[Option[String]]("a")
res21: Option[String] = Some(abc)

scala> avMap.grab[String]("a")
java.util.NoSuchElementException: no suitable value for key: a
  at AnyValMap$.$anonfun$grab$extension$1(<console>:32)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at AnyValMap$.grab$extension(<console>:32)
  ... 31 elided
```